# CoreDNS not moving to ready state

Tags: coredns

I'm building out my Raspian Kubernetes Cluster and I've got just about everything working.. exception.

The coredns in one my worker nodes won't move to ready state.

```
kube-system   coredns-66bff467f8-brqt9 1/1  Running   0  82s 10.244.0.14  master-001
kube-system   coredns-66bff467f8-qlz27 0/1  Running   0  58s 10.244.1.16  worker-001
```

So the worker-001 node won't move to ready.

A few of the last lines from the Kubectl logs on the non ready pod:

```
E0528 02:11:45.336779       1 reflector.go:153] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:105: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/endpoints?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout  
I0528 02:11:45.339521       1 trace.go:116] Trace[2003272451]: "Reflector ListAndWatch" name:pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:105 (started: 2020-05-28 02:11:15.338624567 +0000 UTC m=+589.077169723) (total time: 30.00076228s): Trace[2003272451]: [30.00076228s] [30.00076228s] END  
E0528 02:11:45.339899       1 reflector.go:153] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:105: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout 
[INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes"
```

So it looks like the worker is still waiting for something, I just don't know what.

I am using Flannel on this cluster.  If I ssh to the worker node, I can ping a university's domain name and get a valid respond.

PS: Raspian - Buster, Kubernetes is 1.18.3, Flannel is listed as version 0.12.0-s390x

On a whim, I unplugged worker-001, deleted the worker pod, and let it recreate on worker-002 and got no difference.

So what would be the next thing to check to get CoreDNS to move to a ready state?

Thanks for any advice,
Nick

Answer (score 1):

I switched from Flannel to Weave and that it came right up.  Not sure why Flannel was't working.